# Fetching Post metadata failed

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-graph-api, instaloader

I am trying to fetch post likes user names from IG using Instaloader . But I am seeing this error in some posts **Fetching Post metadata failed** . Can anyone please guide me what's this error mean ? I try to find on google but not fit solution or reason.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, post.shortcode) 
 for like in Post.get_likes():
print(like.username)